# How to refresh the particular div in angular application

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In my project, I need to change the content of a particular div. How can reload the content of the div when a button is clicked?

I am using the angularjs, node, and HTML in my project. The `window.reload` option reloads the whole application; I don't want the page reloaded, just the particular div on one page.

Comment: Improved language and added angularjs tag

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `$scope.$apply()`, or `$scope.$digest()`, but if you have a need to do this, chances are, you're doing something wrong. Maybe you could provide us with your code?

Bear in mind that if you haven't changed anything inside the model of that particular element or directive, no changes will occur. $apply() will simply tell Angular that you've made some changes to the model from the outside, that Angular is not aware of, and that it should fire it's watchers and see if anything needs to be re-rendered.

Let us know if it worked.

Comment: These two is not i asked i need to reload one div, in this div having some data i need reload all the data and show on that div while click refresh button.

Comment: Can you edit the original question and paste entire code there, both html as well as javascript? It's hard to get around the code in the comments. Also, by the snippets you provided, it does not seem you're using anything AngularJS specific.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i got answer it's working for me

```
$route.reload(putyourJsonObject);
```

Here `$route.reload` is used to reload my data.